# Bases of H and its orthogonal complement

Tags: linear-algebra

I would just like to preface this by acknowledging that this question has been asked in various forms, but it's still something which is a bit unclear to me and couldn't come to a concrete conclusion.

Suppose I have H to be defined as:

\begin{bmatrix}1&2&-3&0\\0&3&2&-1\end{bmatrix}

then in order to work out the basis for H I augment it with a zero vector and work out the nullspace, and use the solution set to write its basis?

Then for H(perp), I would take the transpose of this matrix, namely:

\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\2&3\\-3&2\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}

and then follow the same argument I did and this will give me the basis for H(perp)?

Or have I got my wires crossed and it should instead be the other way round?

---

So now, suppose I have H:=Span(**a**, **b**, **c**) where **a**,**b**,**c** are defined thusly:

\begin{bmatrix}-1\\3\\1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}2\\9\\2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}5\\12\\5\end{bmatrix}

then to work out bases for H and H(perp) I would just carry out the same procedure as above?

---

I know how to compute the bases, just a bit confused as to which one I'd be doing it for when taking the transpose.

Thanks in advance for any assistance on this matter.

Comment: I am not sure why you would have to "augment it with the a zero vector".  The 0 vector is already of that form with a= b= c= d= e= f= g= h= 0.  Further, a basis consists of the 8 matrices

Comment: Ah yes, I think I see my error in the question that I'm trying to ask. Edited accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean by the basis of a matrix?

Comment: BTW, there’s never much point to augmenting a matrix with a column of zeroes before row-reduction. That column will remain zero throughout and just clutters things up.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would have to "augment it with the a zero vector".  The 0 vector is already of that form with a= b= c= d= e= f= g= h= 0.  Further, a basis consists of the 8 matrices 
$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Are you clear on what "orthogonal complement" **means**?  In order to have an "orthogonal complement" of a vector space, it has to be a subspace of an inner product space.  What is that vector space and what inner product does it have?

Comment: Apologies once again, I have since edited it to a specific example which I found as I felt as though I confused myself with the "a,b,c..."